# get vim working in mobaxterm

Tags: windows, vim

I have installed gvim and vim in mobaxterm 8 (using apt-get and mobapt respectively), and can't get either to work. nano works fine.

When I run the program, the cursor moves to a new line in the terminal but nothing happens.

I have also tried creating a .vimrc. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Try to check if you have Gvim.mxt3 in the same directory as MobaXterm executable.

Comment: Yep, have the mxt3 in the same folder, same thing happens. I am on Win10 x64 if that makes any difference?

Comment: Sorry, but probably the best shot is [to write them](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/documentation.html#6_8_8).

Answer (score 2):

I installed the latest version of MobaXterm as up today which is 9.1 (http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download-home-edition.html) and the list of bug fixes includes the freezing problem you are are talking about. It works for me now and I no longer see that issue. The only thing is that after the installation is completed you need to download the CygUtils plugin and copy it to the same folder where the MobaXterm executable is located and then restart the application. It seems overall more stable now. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am using V9.4 which already has the vim. To configure the environment for your vim you may creat a .vimrc file in your home directory (go to the directory using cd command only).

Comment: is there a link to documentation about `vimrc` file creation?

Comment: @varontron yes—open vim and run `:help vimrc`

Comment: You can create the file with vim itself (vim .vimrc) 
Then put individual commands in separate lines and save it like- 
:set nu ------>For displaying line number
:set cindent ------> to turn C indentation on
etc.